# How to output the registry value of any type

Tags: c++, registry

Registry value has many type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, REG_BINARY, REG_DWORD,...

I can get the registry value data (of data type DWORD_PTR) by the function RegQueryMultipleValues, but depend on each registry value type, I have to find a way to cast the value to output it. I have been thinking to decide to use the word output in the question to make it clear that I have the values - but have difficulty output it.

For example, I have the code below

Here I get a list of registry value

```
nErrorCode = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\VIDEO"), 0, KEY_READ, &hOpenKey);
PVALENT val_list;//List registry data
DWORD num_vals; //The length of val_list
LPTSTR lpValueBuf;//the buffer receives the data for each value
DWORD ldwTotsize;//the size of the buffer pointed to by the lpValueBuf parameter
//Some code to assign these value above...
//Now get the values of the list registry
RegQueryMultipleValues(hOpenKey, val_list, num_vals, lpValueBuf, &ldwTotsize);
```

Now I try to output these values with the baby steps

```
VALENT crtReg;
DWORD dwValue;
DWORD* pDwValue;
for (int i = 0; i < num_vals; i++)
{
    crtReg = val_list[i];
    switch (crtReg.ve_type)
    {
    case REG_DWORD:
        /*This is ok*/
        pDwValue = (DWORD*)crtReg.ve_valueptr;
        dwValue = *pDwValue;
        std::cout << "DWORD Key name: \n"
            << crtReg.ve_valuename
            << "\n value: "
            << dwValue
            << "\n len: "
            << crtReg.ve_valuelen;
        std::cout << "\n===========\n";
        break;
    case REG_SZ:
        /*This is ok*/
        std::cout << "String Key name: \n"
            << crtReg.ve_valuename
            << "\n value: "
            << (TCHAR*)crtReg.ve_valueptr
            << "\n len: "
            << crtReg.ve_valuelen;
        std::cout << "\n===========\n";

        break;
    case REG_BINARY:
        /*Tricky...*/
        std::cout << "Binary Key name: \n"
            << crtReg.ve_valuename
            << "\n value: (wait implement)"
            << "\n len: "
            << crtReg.ve_valuelen;
        std::cout << "\n===========\n";
        break;
    default:
        /*Really tricky...*/
        std::cout << "Else Key name: \n"
            << crtReg.ve_valuename
            << "\n value: (wait implement)"
            << "\n len: "
            << crtReg.ve_valuelen;
        std::cout << "\n===========\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I switch case and cast the value for each type, but there is types that I don't know how to cast - like binary, and others (Ok, I only know how to cast DWORD and SZ type). Please help me if there is a way to output any type, even in the future there is new type like REG_ULTIMATE_3D (I thought MS provide a function but I searched and couldn't find it - maybe there is but I'm not good enough to find it). If there is no way to output any type, please teach me how to output each type.

Comment: PS: about the REG_SZ case I used TCHAR*, if the character is normal latin, it can read fine, but if it is some non-latin char like Korea, Chinese, Japanese,.. then the TCHAR* can't handle it - but I see regedit tool can handle it - how did regedit tool did that???

Comment: you are using `std::cout`, which works for ANSI data in the user's default locale. If `TCHAR` maps to `char`, you are fine (`RegQueryMultipleValues()` will output in the correct ANSI format), otherwise you have to convert the data using `WideCharToMultiByte()`, or use `std::wcout` instead. There are tons on questions on StackOverflow about how to send Unicode text to console output.

Comment: This topic has the function FormatDataWithDataType do just that, but there are still some case that didn't implement.  http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/registry/article.php/c5671/Exporting-the-Registry-Through-the-Program.htm